# how to autowire interface using @Component in non spring boot project

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, autowired

I am working on non spring boot project and I am using jpa for orm , in that I have to use repository which is of type interface and I have declared repository as @Component and When I am trying to @Autowired it is not working .

```
@Component
public interface RepositoryExampleTable extends CrudRepository<ExampleTable, String> {

}
```

And I am autowiring like :

```
@Autowired(required=true)
RepositoryExampleTable repositoryExampleTable ;
```

When I use spring boot and declared class as @SpringBootApplication then it automatically create bean of type RepositoryExampleTable

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.10.5.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.create-instances

Comment: can we create bean using @Component in non spring boot project

Comment: Yes, of course. `@Component` is a Spring gframework annotation. But that's irrelevant here. Read the linked manual section to know how to properly define spring-data-jpa repositories.